# How to pass shell arguments with VBoxManage guestcontrol?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, virtualbox, guest-additions

I run a command from the host machine on the guest machine (both Ubuntu) as

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol Ubuntu1 run --exe "script.sh" --username xx --password xx --wait-stdout
```

where the shell script on the guest machine is as

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

How can I pass the argument 1 while executing the shell script?

I assumed it should work as

```
run --exe "script.sh arg1"
```

but it does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### SSH

We can run an application on a virtual guest with an SSH session from the host to this machine. However this requires that networking was enabled, and that **[openssh-server](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssh-server)** was installed an runs on the guest machine.

#### VBoxManage guestcontrol

As an alternative we can use built-in features of Virtual Box to execute a program on a running guest VM. This can be done with [`VBoxManage guestcontrol`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol).

The example line below will just run `ls` on the virtual machine's root:

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "<vm_name>" run --exe "/bin/ls" --username <guestuser> --password <password> --wait-stdout
```

Running a graphical application on the guest requires us to define the DISPLAY environment variable to the guest with the option `--putenv`. Next example will run and open gedit on the guest:

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "<vm_name" run --exe "/usr/bin/gedit" --username <guestuser> --password <password> --putenv "DISPLAY=:0" --wait-stdout
```

We can also pass options to open a program. Next example will open a file `vmtest` in the guest gedit:

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "vm_name" run --exe "/usr/bin/gedit" --username <guestuser> --password <password> --putenv "DISPLAY=:0" --wait-stdout -- gedit/arg0 vmtest
```

Options and arguments are separated from the command with `--` as can best be seen in below example of a script from the host.

---

#### Example host script

Below script will play an `example.ogg` file using `paplay` in a guest machine when run on the host. Replace the variables with appropriate values.

```
#!/bin/bash

VM_NAME=myvm
VM_USER=takkat
VM_PASSWD=topsecret
VM_EXEC=paplay
VM_EXEC_PATH=/usr/bin/paplay
VM_ARGS=/home/takkat/Music/example.ogg

VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol $VM_NAME run --exe $VM_EXEC_PATH \
--username $VM_USER --password $VM_PASSWD --wait-stdout \
-- {$VM_EXEC}/arg0 $VM_ARGS
```

Comment: Sorry, I got lost. Where do you `argv1` in `guestcontrol` command?

Comment: @All it is named `arg0`. In the gedit example line it is `-- gedit/arg0` then  `vmtest` to open a file `vmtest` in the guest's gedit, in the example script it is the variable VM_ARGS that plays an ogg file in the guest and from the guest hard drive. Remember to always give full paths.

Comment: Wonderful! Works like a charm.

Comment: above and beyond, wish I had more than one vote to give.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the wonderfully detailed reply you put together!